# Animation inside Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking for a way to provide animations inside bootstrap carousel. I am building an event website where in the carousel I need to put information about the event (That should be some text supported by animations).

Is there any way I could do that. I am a beginner int this.

Comment: There are information described in the bootstrap website http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel. I don't know exactly what you need but I'm quite sure that you can achieve it by reading the website above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ways to do this.

### Option #1 (js)

Use the `slid.bs.carousel` event, fired when a slide transition is completed :

```css
.carousel-caption {
    bottom: 600px;
}
```

```js
$('#carousel-example-captions').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $(this).find('.active .carousel-caption').animate(
        {bottom: '20px'},
        '1000'
    );
})
```

### Option #2 (no-js)

Use CSS3 transitions, with `.active` class :

```css
.carousel-caption {
    bottom: 600px;
    transition: bottom 1s ease;
}
.active .carousel-caption {
    bottom: 20px;
}
```